# How to change RGB values from colormode(255) to colormode(1)?

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle

turtle.colormode(255)

turtle.color(130, 50, 50)
```

If I set the color mode to 1: `turtle.colormode(1)`, what are the RGB values should I put here? `turtle.color(?, ?, ?)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it to `1.0` means the `rgb` values should be in the range `[0, 1.0]`, which you can get by dividing each component in `255` mode by `255`:

```
import turtle

turtle.colormode(1.0)

turtle.color(130/255, 50/255, 50/255)
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> Return the colormode or set it to 1.0 or 255. Subsequently r, g, b values of color triples have to be in the range 0..cmode.

So, if `cmode` is `1`, you'll need decimal RGB values (130 / 255, 50 / 255, 50 / 255 below):

```
turtle.color(0.51, 0.197, 0.197)
```

This is particularly useful with the `colorsys` module, whose arguments are also in that range:

```
r, g, b = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(0.2, 1, 1)  # bright orange HSV
turtle.color(r, g, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your colormode is set to `1.0`, so either the individual color coordinates need to be **floats** in the range `0.0` to `1.0`. Use float `/` division operator.

Therefore, divide the `r`, `g`, `b` values by `255`.

```
r = 130/255
g = 50/255
b = 50/255
color = (r, g, b)
turtle.color(color)
```